# MYSQL find related query

Tags: mysql, database

I'm writing a query where I'm looking to pull related fields from a database with a limit of 10 rows.

The query is easy to write, however I was wondering if there is a way to write the query so it searches for related items and pulls those first and if those are < 10 it will just pull random fields for the remaining ones.

Here is the query I use to pull the related rows

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE term LIKE '%term1%' or term LIKE '%term2%' LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: My idea, could work, I think : select 10 with union of random 10 and then LIMIT the result to 10.

Comment: To clarify, if a given set of two search terms yields less than 10 results, you want to fill the resultset with random non-duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1):

Your just need to order the table by the terms that you are looking for first, one way of doing this is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table 

ORDER BY (
  (
    CASE WHEN term LIKE '%term1%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN term LIKE '%term2%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  )
) DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: @Dave it is considered polite to accept an answer if it answers your question.